# Check label value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dom

```
<label id="error_msg"></label>
```

Now, I want to alert a message that please fill text-box, whenever there is change in value of `error_msg`

Also, I want to check whether label is empty or not. If label is empty, then alert should not come.

I wrote the code, but it's not working somehow

```
$("#error_msg").change(function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

Help guys.

Comment: for one thing, you're using labels the wrong way :) try using a span or a p tag instead. second, the alert will not come since you're not changing anything. or do you have code that changes the text of label?

Comment: @corroded: label will be updated using some other code

Comment: please also show the code. does that actually change the label?

Comment: are you trying to validate ??

Comment: @corroded: It's done via jQuery Validation plugin

Comment: @experimentX: yes, I am trying to validate

Comment: You are trying to validate using jquery-Validate plugin, i think they provide auto error placement, why do you need alert ?? If there are multiple fields, you certainly don't want to get multiple messages.

Comment: @experimentx he's probably just debugging something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to monitor Dom changes for label. Check out the easy to use jQuery plugin at http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

If you are trying to validate, i highly suggest using the validation plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet been able to test this out, but assuming you're changing your label with JavaScript could you not manually fire change()

Eg

```
$("#error_msg").text("hello").change();
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with. I was updating the value of a label myself with JavaScript and needed the `change` event to fire and this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `change()` method only works with certain elements and `label` is not one of them.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to input elements, textarea boxes and select elements.

Answer (score 0):

The change event doesn't get triggered if you change an element's text/value through JavaScript - it only happens when the *user* changes something (say the text in an input, or the selected item in a select).

If you control the code that sets your label's text, you can write a custom function that both sets the text as well as runs your "event handler", and call this function whenever you want to change `#error_msg`'s text:

```
function set_error_msg(txt)
{
    $('#error_msg').text(txt);
    if(txt)
    {
        //There's text in the label - show your alert...
    }
}
```

But if the change is coming from somewhere else (code outside of your control), you'll have to start up a loop that checks every XXX seconds to see if the text has changed - a process known as Busy Waiting, and generally considered a Bad Thing...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the query validate plugin will auto change the error label. Further i have following script for validation and error placement.

```
$('#account').validate({
    rules:{
            username: {required: true},
            password: {required: true},
            email: {required: true, email: true},
            fullname: {required: true}},
    messages: {
            username: "Category name is required",
            password: "Password is required",
            fullname: "Full Name is required",
            email: "Valid email is required"
        },      
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            $(element).each(function (){
            $(this).parent('td').find('p.error').html(error);
        });
}})
```

And the html goes like this

```
    <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" size="40"/>
    <p class="error"></p>
    </td>
```

Now if you are planning to **ALERT** error message, then

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            var errors = new Array();
            $(element).each(function (){
            $(this).parent('td').find('p.error').html(error);
            errors.push(error);
        });
        alert(errors.join(" "));
    }
```